# aid the corrupted file (binary) in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

Help fix my mistake!
I have damaged the binary file **route**.
Is it possible to reinstall daemon that contains this binary file "route" ?
How to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This doesn't belong on SO, but ...

Do an

```
yum reinstall net-tools
```

Comment: Yes! It has helped! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @Vitaliy.  And thanks for the downvotes w/o comments, guys.